I have two methods of solving the equation $-u^2 = -1$.
I came up with two ways of solving the following equation:
$$-u^2 = -1\qquad (\blacktriangle)$$
First method:

divide both sides of the equation by $-1$ (or multiply by $-1$):  $u^2 = 1$
take the square root of both sides: $u = \sqrt{1} = \pm 1$
get two solutions: $u_1 = 1, u_2 = -1$

substituting $u_1$ or $u_2$ into $(\blacktriangle)$ yields:
$$-(1)^2 = -1\:\Longrightarrow\:-1 = -1$$
$$-(-1)^2 = -1\:\Longrightarrow\:
-1 = -1$$
The equation holds true, thus the solutions are correct
Second method:

take the square root of both sides: $\sqrt{-u^2} = \sqrt{-1}$
factor out $-1$ on the l.h.s: $\sqrt{-1\cdot u^2} = \sqrt{-1}$
apply the identity $\sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}$ on the l.h.s: $\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{u^2} = \sqrt{-1}$
divide by $\sqrt{-1}$ on both sides: $\sqrt{u^2} = \sqrt{-1}/\sqrt{-1} = 1$
simplyfy: $u = 1$

My question:
Why is it that the second method loses the negative solution: $u = -1$?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The identity $\sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}$ is not valid in general, as you can see if you let $a=b=-1$

In step 4 of the second method, you conclude $~\sqrt{u^2} = 1.$
In step 5, you then simplify to $~u = 1.$
Going from step 4 to step 5 is invalid, because you are assuming that $~\sqrt{u^2} = u.$
In actual fact:

$u \geq 0 \implies \sqrt{u^2} = u.$
$u < 0 \implies \sqrt{u^2} = -u.$

So, the valid way of completing the second method would be to reason that

Either $~[ ~u \geq 0~$ and $~u = 1 ~],$

Or $~[ ~u < 0~$ and $~-u = 1~].$



Because √(u^2) is not equal to u, in the process of opening a square, the positive and negative of u is eliminated. It's like √(1^2)=1,and√((-1)^2)=1
